# Exception While working with complex join query

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jdbc

What is the meaning of following exception :

> ```
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
>   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
> ```

---

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:653)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error comes when the hibernate dialect is unable to find the corresponding java data type for your respective database column. Do the columns compatibility check again.